# two event listeners after each other only first one works JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, event-listener

I am creating a paint application. I am painting on the canvas by creating a div with a background color each time I click on my canvas. Since I also want to paint while having clicked and dragged, I created a boolean to see if the user has clicked before executing the code in the mousemove event listener. When I put one event listener in my changeCanvas function that one works but when I put the mousedown and mouseover in the changeCanvas function the second one doesn't work.
Here is the code, my HTML only consists of two divs. One pallet div and one canvas div. Thanks!!

```
var selectedColour = 0;
var paint = false;
var colours = ["red", "yellow", "green", "black", "gray"];

function createPallet(){
    for (var i = 0; i < colours.length; i++){
        var colour = document.createElement("div");
        colour.classList.add("colour");
        var pallet = document.getElementById('pallet');
        pallet.style.width="100px";
        pallet.style.height="300px";
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.style.width="500px";
        canvas.style.height="300px";
        colour.style.backgroundColor = colours[i];
        colour.id = colours[i];
        pallet.appendChild(colour);
        colour.addEventListener("click", pickCol);
    }   
}

function pickCol(e){
    selectedColour = e.target.id;

    console.log(selectedColour);
}

function changeCanvas(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", paint);
}
function mouseDown(){
    paint=true;
}

function paint(e){
    if(paint){
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.classList.add("newDiv"); 
        newDiv.style.backgroundColor = selectedColour;
        canvas.appendChild(newDiv);
        console.log(e.pageX);
        console.log(e.pageY);
        newDiv.style.width= "5px";
        newDiv.style.height= "5px";
        newDiv.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
        newDiv.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
        newDiv.style.position="absolute";
    }
}

createPallet();
changeCanvas();
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML and turn this into an executable stack snippet?

Comment: @Gideonk whenever you post a visual problem always post full code including styles or better post a working demo.Nobody has time to guess your classes